# How to enforce Url route values in MVC Pipeline in a multi tenant app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following default route

```
url: "{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { tenant="not_set", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
constraints: new { tenant= new TenantConstraint()}
```

I have user1 who should only have access to `tenant1/{Controller}/{action}`. 
If the user tried to hack the url to `tenantNoAccess/{Controller}/{action}`, i want him to be automatically redirected to `tenant1/{Controller}/{action}`.

I can do this in an ActionFilter, but I don't want the request to go that far ahead in the mvc pipeline.
I want to do something before the request tries to MapRequestHandler().

I was thinking maybe in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()?...
I have the following in the event

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object o, EventArgs args)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    var user = context.User;
    var request = context.Request;
    var requestUrl = request.Url;
    var reqContext = request.RequestContext;

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
            var usr = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)user;
            string correctTenant = GetCorrectTenantForUser(usr);
            if (!reqContext.RouteData.Values["tenant"].Equals(correctTenant))
            {
                //stuck here. How to change the URL without referencing a 3rd party Url rewrite module?
            }
            else 
            {
                //tenant matches
                return;
            }
    }
    else
    {
      //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In RouteConfig you could add a routehandler.

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}           ).RouteHandler = new LandingPageRouteHandler();
```

In the routehandler you can do the checks you need and set the appropriate controller, action, .....

```
public class LandingPageRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext Context)
    {
        if ( <perform checks)
        {
            Context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = <whateveryouwant>;
            Context.RouteData.Values["action"] = <whateveryouwant>; 
            Context.RouteData.Values["id"] = <whateveryouwant>;
        }
        return base.GetHttpHandler(Context);
    }
}
```

Comment: With this approach the url in the address bar remains website.com/tenantNoAccess. I want to have the user redirected to website.com/tenant1 which the user has access to. Any way to achieve this?